# Python Requests 403 Error On Some Pages of Website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I am looking to scrape prices for different products from Metro's online grocery store. To do this, I need to set a particular store as a "favourite" so that Metro knows which products to show. I'm currently using Selenium to automate this part and return the cookies after selecting a particular store. However, I am still getting 403 errors when passing the cookies to a Request despite the fact that I can access other pages on Metro's website.

```
import requests
import time
from user_agent import generate_user_agent
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agent = generate_user_agent(navigator="chrome")
header = {"User-Agent": user_agent}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)


def getMetroCookies(store_url): 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe")
    browser.delete_all_cookies()
    stealth(browser,
            languages=["en-US", "en"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )
    browser.get(store_url)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    cookie_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/button")
    cookie_button.click()
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[3]/button")))
    store_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button")
    time.sleep(1)
    store_button.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver_cookies = browser.get_cookies()
    c = {c['name']:c['value'] for c in driver_cookies}
    browser.close()
    return(c)


store_url = "https://www.metro.ca/en/find-a-grocery/164"
cookies = getMetroCookies(store_url)

base_url = "https://www.metro.ca/en/online-grocery/search?filter="
search_item = "chicken"
search_url = base_url+search_item
page = requests.get(search_url, headers=header, cookies=cookies)
content = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

This gives me a 403 error along with the following page content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>
<meta id="captcha-bypass" name="captcha-bypass"/>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots"/>
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" id="cf_styles-css" media="screen,projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!-->
<script>
  if (!navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var cookieEl = document.getElementById('cookie-alert');
      cookieEl.style.display = 'block';
    })
  }
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "interactive",
        cNounce: "94024",
        cRay: "6657c0090c70ecee",
        cHash: "f2ab1c66a7c7fb9",
        cFPWv: "g",
        cTTimeMs: "4000",
        cLt: "n",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubWV0cm8uY2EvZW4vb25saW5lLWdyb2Nlcnkvc2VhcmNoP2ZpbHRlcj1jaGlja2Vu",
          ra: "TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV09XNjQpIEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0LzUzNy4zNiAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIENocm9tZS81NC4wLjI4ODIuNzQgU2FmYXJpLzUzNy4zNg==",
          rm: "R0VU",
          d: "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",
          t: "MTYyNDcyNDI5Mi4wMTcwMDA=",
          m: "SuNqM4NyxmnA1WU+nYefP0zkF5LxO+2HK+JlYjzu4dw=",
          i1: "Z/V7+yIdblkqF9PRfarDwA==",
          i2: "iMe97FeUtyqejNZ6Ziyc8w==",
          zh: "/vdKLh0CrKHrnBUka1HcvI1mkhoFozUewI640Q15E4c=",
          uh: "wSvBDgWWw4CCletn46YSZpWn4A/qjMkCb4uV9eAjmfA=",
          hh: "56bTGUAA35o0NPPIwaihW3gLWiRsmO2PeArMwpTuU9E=",
        }
      };
    }());
    //]]>
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
  #cf-wrapper #spinner {width:69px; margin:  auto;}
  #cf-wrapper #cf-please-wait{text-align:center}
  .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
  .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
  #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
  #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
  #cf-hcaptcha-container iframe { display: inline-block;}
  @keyframes fader     { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
  #cf-wrapper #cf-bubbles { width:69px; }
  @-webkit-keyframes fader { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
  #cf-bubbles > .bubbles { animation: fader 1.6s infinite;}
  #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s;}
  #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" data-translate="enable_cookies" id="cookie-alert">Please enable cookies.</div>
<div class="cf-error-details-wrapper" id="cf-error-details">
<div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
<h1 data-translate="challenge_headline">One more step</h1>
<h2 class="cf-subheadline"><span data-translate="complete_sec_check">Please complete the security check to access</span> www.metro.ca</h2>
</div>
<div class="cf-section cf-highlight cf-captcha-container">
<div class="cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-columns two">
<div class="cf-column">
<div class="cf-highlight-inverse cf-form-stacked">
<form action="/en/online-grocery/search?filter=chicken&amp;__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=0641319015a45358b1db60468c92bf88af4a70ea-1624724292-0-ATxUvClOko_GDrF_ejLwzZX-kuPRpoh1BFTlbPpgnM7UZS0tt0LcTa6u0ksaDrdsCuFkwxbyL7QYwbUeX6srjGPdlhXjLsQNqAH5sr4WHG8JX55aU2kRJzjzY9HulNoXyr6MuhmU1HzLv1ZvLss4X5hP-lABtnHTc5waDyQNzn3zxVHYetOu-uA7COqv76by9yx8dhQAWX0pT8cgjYQ2QwRLhrAw49GqhCux2EluSfziYo-Zqncf4uDyMe0Pb7Hb1csz2l9E_L26erOLQTrM_U2c1sYY0T-4ofJdQNEVLFA7e1FkGspeuGaFRRNmcXhCNPB7YKEiHlkROpAr2nxQeepJuefHBMdzbixJRXE5glhNCX9XXJ5nbpo8OzLY7pnMrJgaW6_YucjLh0fJs4c0bfBHAHZLWQeGxvcG7_AeM3zY6MIXngvnXg64GyrpxmYfADy_znyKmVlTCvVwdc8VEBZo27I4iGoqhJWaG0E1Q0Dw9a6dTU7bOWCSpoaxSNUmNkuwL5VsBAk3paSDIwYaewFLHijU-PUdeGw9hcLFsNbD95qUGlVEHZsdUMg176NYJ1VyZho1MMbNj8bVVC2kDKyZOu1IqcMe0TTqVwV5p9j_zZU6ODLXhn_d2VFULBMQTs9eIZUIz3j6uMZdEYV2o53P421SCx-MPPD5rALfYHdTRmSBDCLeW7gUG5-UvnWh87p87HJH__7plEmoJhFkW8crBpUeKBhwt7JQR_huvqOW" class="challenge-form interactive-form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="challenge-form" method="POST">
<div id="cf-please-wait">
<div id="spinner">
<div id="cf-bubbles">
<div class="bubbles"></div>
<div class="bubbles"></div>
<div class="bubbles"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p data-translate="please_wait" id="cf-spinner-please-wait">Please stand by, while we are checking your browser...</p>
<p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting...</p>
</div>
<input name="r" type="hidden" value="86274ebf891ca5903cedef6f5476291f7a3f2375-1624724292-0-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"/>
<input name="cf_captcha_kind" type="hidden" value="h"/>
<input name="vc" type="hidden" value="cb7d9f733e82b2a322f24468dd51d0a0"/>
<noscript class="cf-captcha-info" id="cf-captcha-bookmark">
<h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
</noscript>
<div class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" id="no-cookie-warning" style="display:none">
<p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
      b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
      b(function(){
        var cookiesEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false;
        if(!cookiesEnabled){
          var q = document.getElementById('no-cookie-warning');q.style.display = 'block';
        }
      });
  //]]>
  </script>
<div id="trk_captcha_js" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/nojs/h/transparent.gif?ray=6657c0090c70ecee')"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
        var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
        var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/captcha/js/transparent.gif?ray=6657c0090c70ecee");
        trkjs.id = "trk_captcha_js";
        trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo=document.createElement('script');
        cpo.type='text/javascript';
        cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/captcha/v1?ray=6657c0090c70ecee";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-column">
<div class="cf-screenshot-container">
<span class="cf-no-screenshot"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
<div class="cf-columns two">
<div class="cf-column">
<h2 data-translate="why_captcha_headline">Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?</h2>
<p data-translate="why_captcha_detail">Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary access to the web property.</p>
</div>
<div class="cf-column">
<h2 data-translate="resolve_captcha_headline">What can I do to prevent this in the future?</h2>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_antivirus">If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with malware.</p>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_network">If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network administrator to run a scan across the network looking for misconfigured or infected devices.</p>
<p data-translate="resolve_captcha_privacy_pass"> Another way to prevent getting this page in the future is to use Privacy Pass. You may need to download version 2.0 now from the <a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/privacy-pass/ajhmfdgkijocedmfjonnpjfojldioehi" rel="noopener noreferrer">Chrome Web Store</a>.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
<p class="text-13">
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">6657c0090c70ecee</strong></span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">•</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Your IP</span>: 2607:fa49:3801:a800:6901:b6b5:6c3a:ec5</span>
<span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">•</span>
<span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
</p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is that I'm doing something wrong when extracting the cookies as I am able to access pretty much any part of Metro's website using requests, but I'm pretty new to this so I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like it is asking your scraper to fill in a CAPTCHA to prove it's human.

Answer (score 2):

The website uses Cloudflare services so that it will prevent the request without browser interaction. When you send a request without browser interaction (JavaScript), it will activate a captcha to check whether you are a bot or not. You can use selenium to scrape the information from the website.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = 'https://www.metro.ca/en'

chrome_driver = 'C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(link)
cookie = [f"{c['name']}={c['value']};" for c in driver.get_cookies()]
cookie = ' '.join([elem for elem in cookie])
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#header--search--input')
search.send_keys("chicken")
submitButton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#header--search--button")
submitButton.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
content = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(content)
```

[image]

Using requests

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = 'https://www.metro.ca/en'
chrome_driver = 'C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(link)
cookie = [f"{c['name']}={c['value']};" for c in driver.get_cookies()]
cookie = ' '.join([elem for elem in cookie])

def using_request():
    header = {
        'Host': 'www.metro.ca',
        'Connection': 'close',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'Client-Version': 'web version 2.0',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
        'Origin': 'https://www.metro.ca/en',
        'Referer': 'https://www.metro.ca/en',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Cookie': f"{cookie}"
    }
    search_item = "chicken"
    base_url = f"https://www.metro.ca/en/search?filter={search_item}&freeText=true"
    page = requests.get(base_url, headers=header)
    content = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    print(content)

using_request()
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason why Cloudflare would only protect some parts of the website and not others? Any other page on Metro's website does not give me this error and I can scrape it just fine using requests.

Comment: @SimonSaltine To protect the services from bots, like web scraping, Brute-Force Attack

Comment: I understand the reason why they would use Cloudflare; my question is why does Cloudflare only trigger on this particular webpage on the website and not on any other? I can scrape any other page on their website using requests except for this page.

Comment: @SimonSaltine, I think the request was not successful because one field parameter was not there 'freeText'. Please check the code. Thanks